# Need a way to start a Mirth process, from a Postgres database trigger

Tags: postgresql, mirth

I have limited knowledge about the capabilities of Mirth. What I want to do is have a trigger on an order table and when a new order hits the table, I would like to start up a process on a Mirth Server.  Does anyone know of a way I can make this work?  I guess my question is how do I start a process on the Mirth server?  See, I don't want to poll a table from the Mirth side, because there are certain times of day when the online activity will be VERY high and I don't want something polling the data every few seconds to see if new orders have hit, because orders may only come around two times of the day.  Weird I know, but these are the parameters I have to work with.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, or just point me in the right direction . . .

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information on your environment.

What does "start a Mirth process" mean?   Start a channel?  Post or transmit to an already running channel?

I would also see [Calling RESTful Web Services from PostgreSQL procedure/function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46540352/calling-restful-web-services-from-postgresql-procedure-function)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help but you can use `startChannel` and `stopChannel` methods on [ChannelUtils](http://javadocs.mirthcorp.com/connect/3.11.0/user-api/com/mirth/connect/server/userutil/ChannelUtil.html) to start or stop channels on demand.

Also, under `Polling Settings` from `Database Reader Source Connector` you can select an interval, a time of day, or a custom expression to trigger. More about this in the [User guide, pages 203 and 314](https://www.nextgen.com/-/media/files/nextgen-connect/nextgen-connect-311-user-guide.pdf)