# enriching data from postgres table from a REST API in OLAP use case

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbt

We're using postgres as a data warehouse, which we manage with [dbt](https://www.getdbt.com/).

In it, there is a very large and thin table like this (~10 million rows):

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 'value1' | 123 |
| ... | ... |
| 'valueN' | 123 |

Also, there is a data enrichment API that accepts the existing columns as parameters and returns the relevant enriched data:

```
https://api.myapi.com/&q=value1+123
```

Each API call returns in ~1sec

What is/are performant way/s to enrich the data without leaving the data warehouse such that I can add a third column like so:

| col1 | col2 | enrichedCol |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 'value1' | 123 | enriched1 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 'valueN' | 123 | enrichedN |

Ideally, this is done with SQL or a stored procedure.

Snowflake has [External Functions](https://blog.getcensus.com/data-enrichment-without-leaving-the-warehouse/) that achieve something similar.

We've considered an [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) in a plpython3u stored procedure approach, but I feel that postgres should have a better solution.

An explanation of why doing this is an anti-pattern is also acceptable.

Comment: For context, what's wrong with grabbing the data from the API at the application level when it's needed?

Comment: Can't you just add a new column to your existing table instead of duplicating the whole table content into a new one ?

Comment: There is no application level, this is a dbt project and a OLAP use case

Comment: @Edouard - yeah, that works too

Comment: dbt is just a code-generating-like tool, it compiles the models/macros/custom test/etc to SQL and executes them against the targetted database(s). If you've to perform API calls within dbt = you have to perform API calls by using SQL, and so to use `plpython3u` - that looks like the only solution. But you should consider not to follow this approach as the performance issue with huge dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres and `dbt` guy here, looks like so far this would have been better received on the discourse than the stack-overflow but imo, great question.

Basically, the way I'm interpreting this so far, you are asking about patterns and to be fair, the vast majority of dbt users so far have only used 1, maybe 2 of the architectural "pattern" from what I've seen here. That will change over time as I believe Spark, Firebolt, and the "next-gen" datastores will likely support features like "api to db pipelines as sql" very soon.

I can think of at least 3 options here:

1. Dump to "data lake"
2. ETL / ELT Engine
3. Polling Service (as you suggested)

This would be how I roughly illustrate these patterns for documentation or a project proposal:

[image]

To describe those a little further:

1. Dump everything from the API in bulk to a file (or even better a snapshotted file just in case some data is later redacted) and then make that data available via [dbt-external-tables](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-external-tables) as a view so that you are always merging the latest from the archive at the merge view query time.

Example of this is using a directory structure on a cloud storage service like in the following write-up: [Loading and transforming data into BigQuery using dbt](https://medium.com/google-cloud/loading-and-transforming-data-into-bigquery-using-dbt-65307ad401cd)

2. Use an external service from the database to poll the api with data from the database. (Probably the slowest overall option since the triple network IO of read from DB, read from API, and then write to DB.)

** edit **
(Additional point for clarity, this is *NOT* the same as a source read-only ELT service like Fivetran or Airbyte. Here I'm referring to the pattern of using a service that is capable of doing a read/update or read/upsert operation for the circumstances where that is required like watching an Address table in a DB and then enriching that information with a sanitized version of the address from Google Places API or something equivalent).

3. Create a procedure (ala this [SO Postgres Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46540352/calling-restful-web-services-from-postgresql-procedure-function)
    which, combined with a trigger, could return a value from an external service via a standard cURL call.
   (My view on the problem with this will be maintainability - how will you be alerted if the API changes and extracts unexpected values, how do you log timing & success of the procedure calls, does your DE have control over the DB as well as the dbt code base and can perfectly anticipate how dbt changes will effect this proc?, etc.)

Happy to expand further but would generally recommend re-opening this question over in the `[postgres][rest][webservices]` tags since dbt is mostly irrelevant to the question so far.

Comment: Thanks, @sgoley! Do you have any literature recommendations for option 2 (dbt + airflow)?

Comment: @JoeyBaruch So personally, I would prefer to discuss this more directly with you (see profile to msg on linkedin, etc.) since that is very close to exceeding the "tool-recommendation" guideline of stack-overflow. However, will trying adding some generic examples to my answer with an edit. 
Also may be better to ask on /r/dataengineering reddit as well!

Answer (score 0):

PG should deal with 10mln! :) I would add column to the table, accepting nulls. Then in small chunks, I would update, row by row.

Key factor here is not to lock your table for too long. Also smaller transactions are better in terms of reusing space.

First step allows fast exclusive lock to be really short. That only changes metadata of the table - since nulls are allowed, last column is null by default, if row ends sooner - all columns after that are null by design.

Next changing - should be done in chunks. That way free-space-map can handle each chunk, and next one should reuse space left by previous one. Read about MVCC if you need more information. Update changes indexes (also MVCC explains that), that adds to FSM, also if you need particular data order, index  structure - be aware.

Question about anti-patern. Well, if you have all the data at the server, and your PG is quite new - you can do it with [stored procedure / anonymous block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-transactions.html). Just commit every 1000-2000 updates. Other option - external script. I would recommend triggering it from the server with screen... Just as good practice. On the other hand - it should just pick next 1000-2000 rows with nulls, so failure should not be a big deal. If that is too much for the server - due to high load from other sources - just add some some [sleep](https://database.guide/how-pg_sleep-works-in-postgresql/).